# How to calculate values of few rows cell from other cells in panda?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a big CSV dataset consists of Lat, long, date and soil moisture value. I have obtained them from root folders (saved by date) and using 'glob' function. Now I would like to replace some of the soil moisture values (values=1) with mean values of neighbouring grids that are to be identified by lat/long.

But I would like to implement the following dataframe:

[image: This is just the data I am getting now from the script]

But I would like to implement the following on the dataframe:

```
Lat      Long     Soil moisture
151.10, -33.90 = ((151.10, -33.85)+(151.05, -33.90))/2
151.10, -33.95 = ((151.05,-33.95)+(151.10,-34.00))/2
```

I am new to Python and not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Are you able to share a minimal dataset that is representative of your actual data?

Comment: added a supporting image now!

Comment: An image is not reproducible, please provide code/text/

Answer (score 0):

This code will print the csv file, then update it and then print it again. At the end, it saves the csv file to a file with a different name.

```py
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

print(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    long = row["lon"]
    lat = row["lat"]
    df.at[index, "SM"] = long * lat # fancy formula
    
print(df)

df.to_csv("updated_test.csv", index=False)
```

I don't know which formula you need to use, right now I am just multiplying lat * long.

Comment: Thank you @muhmann. As I understand you straight used the formula for all rows but what about if I need to recalculate for some specific rows with SM values=1 and that is also based on averaging certain neighboring cells? For example a grid cell got 4 neighboring cells but I need to average only two of those? how to specify these conditions in your code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Like, do you need the long/lat values from the rows above/below the row you're calculating SM for?

Comment: Hello @muhmann, sorry for confusion. I am after getting average SM values for some of the neighboring cells (not every neighboring cells). with that value I would like to replace values of cells that got constant (SM =1) values. So I do not want to include those neighboring cells that got constant values into the average. So I need an automated process that would replace the constant values of the cells in interest with the average of neighboring cells that do not have constant values and that is at immediate adjacent.  Immediate adjacent means atleast one arm of the cells is common.

Answer (score 0):

below function will work.
Here I am taking the row wise mean by specifying axis=1 inside the mean function

```
df['SM']=df.loc[:,["lon","lat"]].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you @Sajil Alakkalakath. Can you please write the full code? Just to refine the question, I need recalculation for some specific rows with SM values=1 and that is also based on averaging certain neighboring cells? For example a grid cell got 4 neighboring cells but I need to average only two of those? how to specify these conditions in your code? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to to replace column 'SM' value where where SM=1 then below code will do:

```
df.loc[df['SM']==1,'SM'] =df.loc[df['SM']==1,["col1","col2"]].mean(axis=1)
```

here col1, col2.. are the columns used for averaging.